# How do I change the color of the color below the header?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, color

[image]

I want the color of number 2 to be the same as the color of number 1.

This is the code that I've used:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usecolortheme[RGB={0,0,128}]{structure}
\definecolor{bluenavy}{RGB}{0,0,128}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=bluenavy}
```

Sorry, if the way I wrote it was wrong, but it's the first time I have posted something here.

Thanks.

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!  Please post the code that produced your image(s), that way people who want to help can cut and paste your code to work on it, rather than trying to guess what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks, A Feldman. Now, I think that my asnwer is better explained.

Comment: I guess you are looking for `\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=bluenavy}`

Comment: But please always post complete code i.e. a minimal document people can compile. This is much more helpful than mere fragments.

Comment: @samcarter Do you want to make that comment into an official answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for the remainder. I totally forgot about this question!

Answer (score 1):

The space below the sections is meant for the subsections, so changing its colour works the same way you did for the sections `\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=bluenavy}`

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usecolortheme[RGB={0,0,128}]{structure}
\definecolor{bluenavy}{RGB}{0,0,128}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=bluenavy}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=bluenavy}

\begin{document}
    \frame{}
\end{document}
```